# Float setting is invalid

Tags: html, css

write a code including html and css, in css file: common.css, I write

```
.r {
   float:right;  
}
```

and in html file, wirte:

```
<div class="menu r">

</div>
```

but this div is still at the left side, the code is as follows:
common.css

```
/*header start*/
.headerbg {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
.header {
    width:1200px;
}
.logo {
    display:block;
}
.f {
    float：left;
}
.menu {
    width:570px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
.r {
    float：right;
}
/*header end*/
```

in html file, the code:

```
<div class="headerbg">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo f">
            <img src="images/logo.gif" width="305" height="70" alt="...">
        </a>
        <div class="menu r">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the div class = "menu r" is still at the left side,in chrome, press F12, find:

```
.r {
}
```

no content:float:right,could you tell me why and how to correct it

Comment: Looks like those aren't real colons in your CSS rules for `.f` and `.r`. When I paste what you have into VSC or jsFiddle the syntax highlighters catch a bad colon. In unicode, a colon is `U+003A : COLON`, however you're using `U+FF1A : FULLWIDTH COLON`

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('float:right' === 'float:right')===>result : false
 your code--------^                 ^----------my code
```

```js
console.log('float：right' === 'float:right');
```

```
console.log('float:right'.charCodeAt(5));-->//65306
console.log('float:right'.charCodeAt(5));--->//58
```

so ,problem is in `:` (colon).

may you copied `float:right` from other code.for fix it remove it and copy & paste this code:

```
.r { float: right; }
```

```css
.headerbg {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
.header {
    width:1200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.logo {
    display:block;
}
.f {
    float：left;
}
.menu {
    width:870px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    float：right;
}
.r {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerbg">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="#" class="logo f">
   <img src="images/logo.gif" width="305" height="70" alt="...">
 </a>
    <div class="menu r">ss</div>
  </div>
</div>
```